# GeoPandas Dissolve is turning Multipolygon into Polygon and these are not stored in KML files

Tags: python, kml, geopandas

I have a group of KML files that I want to dissolve using GeoPandas.

I'm reading those files and appending them all into one GeoPandas DataFrame.

```
def get_original_files(files):
    
    gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
    
    original = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['Name','geometry'])
    for file in files:
        gdf = gpd.read_file(file, driver='KML')
        original = original.append(gdf[['Name','geometry']])
    return original
```

Then, I'm using dissolve to aggregate the geometries that have the same Name.

```
original = get_original_files(files)
dissolved = original.dissolve(by='Name', as_index=False)
```

When I save this GeoDataFrame to a KML file, some geometries are missing.

```
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'
dissolved[['Name','geometry']].to_file('file.kml', driver='LIBKML')
dissolved.shape
> (7006,2)
```

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('file.kml', driver='KML')
gdf.shape
> (6994, 3)
```

I noticed that these missing geometries were Multipolygons in the original files, but were turned into Polygons after dissolve.

```
original = get_manchas_gdf(files)
original[original['Name'] == '310020305000023']['geometry']
```

1844    MULTIPOLYGON Z (((-45.44544 -19.14009 0.00000,...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

```
dissolved[dissolved['Name'] == '310020305000023']['geometry']
```

22    POLYGON Z ((-45.44544 -19.14009 0.00000, -45.4...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

I can plot those geometries using geopandas just fine.

[Plot using original files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTzwe.png)

[Plot using dissolved data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOUeb.png)

But when I save the GeoDataFrame to a KML file, these same geometries that were turned into Polygons are missing from the file.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('file.kml', driver='KML')
gdf.shape
> (6994, 3)
```

There should be 7006 rows in the dataframe.

If I save it to a SHP file, everything works just fine, but I need to have a KML working file with all geometries.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This seems like an interesting problem and may (*may*) even be a bug/shortcomming in the way fiona's KML drivers handle intersecting rings. Generally, these types of polygons which have multiple intersections as shown in your image are tricky and can be a buggy or counter-intuitive point for these spatial libraries. However, it's really hard for us to help without a complete example! Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by defining a GeoDataFrame in code with just a few shapes that demonstrate the problem. Thanks!